# Guild/server specific commands

Tags: discord, discord.js

So what I would like to do is allow my bot to do different commands based on the server. For example, if I am in one server and type `!rules` it would show the rules for just that server and if I go into another server it shows other rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the id of a guild when a message is sent by `message.guild.id`. After that you can access the guild object and do a lot with it by `bot.guilds.get(id)` or `client.guilds.get(id)`

So now you can start defining some variables in your actual code

```js
/* Assuming you have a variable called cmd that stores the command called */
if (cmd === 'RULES') {
   let guildId = message.guild.id;
   let guild = bot.guilds.get(guildId); // or replace with client
   // Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare [`Guild#id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id) to the guilds ID. Then you can handle the command differently for each guild.